# SSRS Deployment complaining about path length when my path is short

Tags: deployment, reporting-services

I am attempting to deploy my SSRS solution. I have set the "TargetReportFolder" property of my project to "Reports"

When I right-click and select "Deploy", I get the following error:

> The path of the item '/Reports' is not valid. The full path must be less than 260 characters long; other restrictions apply. If the report server is in native mode, the path must start with slash.

Obviously my path is less than 260 characters long. I've tried setting my TargetReportFolder property to "/Reports", to the name of my project, and to the name of my project with a slash at the beginning - all give the same error.

I don't understand this deployment process very well. Can someone help me understand?

(I also feel like this may not be on topic, but was encouraged by the presence of an SSRS tag)

Comment: Actually, I've found that there is no Reporting Services site in IIS. That's gotta be an issue...

Comment: Nevermind. My problem was that I'm using SharePoint Integrated mode, so I shouldn't even _be_ deploying at all.

Comment: Just FYI, since 2008 SSRS doesn't have a dependency on IIS. It runs it's own webserver with `http.sys`. so unless you're running a very old version you won't have an SSRS site in IIS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My problem was that I didn't understand how Reporting Services works with SharePoint. My comment above is incorrect, I did need to deploy, but I had the wrong parameters for my properties. This page helped me:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb283155.aspx

The key takeaways from this article are:

1. All `Target*Folder` properties need to be either a URL to a document library, or empty
2. If they are empty, they take the value of `TargetReportFolder`, which can't be empty and must be a URL to a document library
3. `TargetServerURL` needs to be the URL of the site collection in SharePoint

Comment: wierd as it may seem, I had 2 tabs open(both containing SSRS url each pointing to different environments.) As soon as i closed one it started working...I dont know the root cause though

Answer (score 1):

Check for extra space at the end of the TargetReportFolder in the Report Server Statistics Property Pages (under "General")